# Linear model least squares estimates with Gram-Schmidt (intercept value inconsistent)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model

I am trying to calculate the least parameters estimates using the Gram-Schmidt algorithm and comparing them to the known formula 
$\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$.

[image: gram-schmidt algorithm steps]

If you follow the formula above, taken from the book Elements of Statistical Learning, we see that the estimate for $\beta_0$ does not depend on $X$. It is simply $\frac{\langle1, y\rangle}{\langle1, 1\rangle} = \bar{y}$. But this is not true if we use the formula to calculate it. For example, if $X = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 3 \\
   1 & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{bmatrix}
   1  \\
   2  \\
   3 \end{bmatrix}$. We have $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = \begin{bmatrix}
   3.5  \\
   -1  \\
   -0.5 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\bar{y} = 2 $.

All the other estimates for $\beta_i$ match - the only discrepancy is on $\beta_0$. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you subtracting the constant term *before* performing the successive orthogonalizations, i.e., as the *first* variable?  When I do the successive orthogonalizations, I don't get the same coefficients.   Also note that in step 2 you do not have an intercept in the regressions.

Comment: What do you mean by "before perming the successive orthogonalizations"? I am subtracting it as the formula tells you to. Yes, there is no $\beta_0$ on step 2 because the residual is already defined on step 1.

Comment: The estimate of $\beta_0$ depends *strongly* on $X.$  Try it: change $X$ and see what happens. For instance, double the second column and triple the third column and redo your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the ordering of the inputs (I had the same confusion initially). The Algorithm as described only gives the coefficient estimate for the $p$th (last) column. So when step 3 says *regress $y$ on the residual $z_p$ to give the estimate $\hat{\beta}_p$* it literally means the *p*th $\hat{\beta}$ rather than *any* coefficient $p$. This is hinted at later on the page when the authors note that *by rearranging the $x_j$, any of them could be in the last position*.

More concretely, to estimate $\hat{\beta}_0$ in your example we could rearrange the order of $X$ as follows

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 3 & 1 \\
   1 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

then is step 1 of the algorithm we instead initialize $z_0 = x_0 = 1$ and run the remainder of the algorithm. This will calculate the coefficient for the final input which in this case is the intercept.

Here is the R code to do just that

```
regress_b_on_a <- function(a, b){
  top <- t(a)%*%b
  bottom <- t(a)%*%a
  beta <- top/bottom
  return(as.numeric(beta))
}

get_residual <- function(a, b, gamma){
  gamma_a <- matrix(rep(0, nrow(a[[1]])))
  for (k in 1:length(gamma)){
    gamma_a <- gamma_a + gamma[k]*a[[k]]
  }
  return(b - gamma_a)
}


# Gram-Schmidt algorithm 
GramSchmidt <- function(X, y) {
  # initialise Z and X_0
  Z <- list()
  Z[[1]] <- X_0 <- matrix(c(1,1,0))
  # follow steps 2 for each column in the data
  for (j in 1:ncol(X)){
    gamma <- matrix(nrow = j)
    for (l in 1:j){
      gamma[l] <- regress_b_on_a(a=Z[[l]], b=X[,j])
    }
    Z[[j+1]] <- get_residual(a=Z, b=X[,j], gamma)
  }
  # step 3: calculate beta p
  print(paste0('Beta:', regress_b_on_a(Z[[j+1]], y)))
}

# test procedure on data  
X <- matrix(c(3,1,1,1,1,1), 3)
y = c(3.5, -1,-0.5)
GramSchmidt(X, y)  # "Beta: -2.75"
```